# $window.scrollTo(0,0) stop working completely with no reason. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, angular-ui-router

I have a web app using AngularJS and ui-router for routing. I have been using `$window.scrollTo(0,0);` to scroll top to each view changes. **It had been working normally**. Now it suddenly stops working and I do not know why. I have been Googling and Stack Overflowing a lot but can't find any answers for that.

```
angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function($event) {
  var scrollY = $event.currentTarget.pageYOffset;
  console.log(scrollY);
});
```

Scroll event was working for me as well, and now it stops working. This really bother me cuz I swear **I did not change any code**. Any ideas would be appreciated.